# How to send emails with smtpjs in reacts without typescript

Tags: html, reactjs, forms

I tried creating a contact form with SMTP js in react but it did not work tried checking stack over flow but no good answer for using only react not typescript

I was expecting the stmp is to be installed like normal swiper

Because I'm still a junior frontend dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also find more information and documentation on using smtp.js in React app on the following resources:

Official smtp.js documentation: https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/smtp.js
SMTP in Node.js: https://nodemailer.com/smtp/

this also explains better:
https://victorbruce82.medium.com/how-to-send-emails-using-react-through-emailjs-no-server-code-needed-8e1453ef8796

Yes, you can install smtp.js in a similar way to installing other packages in your React app. You can use npm or yarn to install it:
CODE :
npm install smtpjs
or
yarn add smtpjs

After installation, you can import and use smtp.js in your React component.